# ggplot: add violin to a line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am drawing a line graph in ggplot. Each line corresponds to one person and their development over time. A simplified, reproducible example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10, 10), y=rnorm(100), person=rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=10))
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, group=person)) + geom_line(aes(color=person))
```

Which produces:

[image]

**I'd like to add a violin at x = 11 to show the overall distribution of the values depicted on the y-axis.**

If I add a `+ geom_violin()` to the ggplot call, a violin will be drawn at each value of x (which makes sense). But what I want is to add the violin I'd get with `ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_violin()`.

How do I combine these two `geom_`s in a single plot to give a full overview of my data?

---

EDIT: I got it to work with `geom_errorbar` but can't get something similar to work with a violin:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, group=person)) + geom_line(aes(color=person)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=11, ymax=mean(dat$y)+sd(dat$y), ymin=mean(dat$y)-sd(dat$y))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=11, y=mean(dat$y)), size=4)
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Ideally, I'd want a violin instead of the error bars to better reflect the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `group = 1` inside of the `aes` of `geom_violin`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = person)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(group = 1), fill = NA, size = 1.5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

this gives:

[image]

To plot the violin next to the line plot you can make use of `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = person)) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14)
p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_violin(fill = NA) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(color = NA),
        axis.text = element_text(color = NA))

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2, widths = c(4,1))
```

which gives:

[image]

However, the line and violin plots are now separated by the legend. With:

```
library(gtable)
leg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1)), "guide-box") 

grid.arrange(p1 + guides(color = FALSE), p2, leg, ncol=3, widths = c(4,1,1))
```

you can place the legend to the far right of the plot again:

[image]

Comment: And is there any way that I can show this violin at x = 11 instead of spanning the whole graph? Ideally, I want it to be displayed between what's now the lines and the legend.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, group=person)) + geom_line(aes(color=person)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(x=rep(11, nrow(dat)), y=y, group=1))
```

Things to note: setting `aes(x=11, y=y)` in `geom_violin()` does not work because (a) x and y have to have the same length and (b) you would get ten violins.

(a) can be avoided by `rep()`'ing the number to create a vector of equal length to `y` and (b) is avoided by setting `group = 1` (as pointed out by Procrastinatus Maximus' answer).

The resulting plot:

[image]

If there's a better solution to this, I'd love to see it!

Comment: This will not give the correct violin plot imo. See also my updated answer

Comment: What do you mean with "not correct"? The violin might show up as a vertical line if the values on the x-axis are larger but that can be adjusted with `geom_violin(..., width=X)` - but the violin *will* contain the data in `y`. What's not correct about that?

Comment: this results in a different shape of the violin

Comment: But isn't that just a matter of how the density is scaled? The data that is used is the same, right?

Comment: But the violin only represents the distribution of the `y` values. Try (in my code) replacing 11 with 4, then 5, then 6. They are all the same violin. In your initial answer (where the violin spans the whole plot on top of the lines), all that's different is the `width` parameter (I think).